# "TypeError: getStaticPaths is not a function" error in Nextjs

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma, trpc, t3

First of I am new in Nextjs and making a blog project using T3 Stack (Nextjs, Typescript, Prisma, tRPC). I get an error like this when I want to pull the post content with the id. I will add my codes as well. I would be glad if anyone can help :)

This is my router:

```
getPost: publicProcedure
    .input(
      z.object({
        postId: z.string(),
      })
    )
    .query(({ ctx, input }) => {
      const { postId } = input;
      return ctx.prisma.post.findUnique({
        where: { id: postId },
        include: { Category: true, author: true },
      });
    }),
```

and this is my postview component:

```
export const PostView: FC<PostViewProps> = ({ id }) => {
  const { data } = api.posts.getPost.useQuery({ postId: id });

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="xl">
      <Box>
        <Image src={"/logo.png"} alt="logo" width={180} height={180} />
      </Box>

      <Typography variant="h4">{data?.title}</Typography>
      <Typography>{data?.content}</Typography>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

I tried many solution methods on the Internet and chatgpt, but I could not pass the error.

Comment: This most likely has something to do with how you pass `id` into the `PostView` component. The actual relevant code is not shown in your provided code. In addition, `ctx.prisma.post` requires an await, and the query handler needs to be `async`

Comment: Thanks for the async warning. Which part of the code do I need to include?

Comment: here `.query(async ({ ctx, input }) => {`

Comment: Do you have `getStaticPaths` defined, too? If so, please share your code

Comment: No, I haven't defined a function like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be more to it, but an immediate correction below. You need to make your handler function `async` and `await` the prisma query.

```
getPost: publicProcedure
    .input(
      z.object({
        postId: z.string(),
      })
    )
    .query(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
      const { postId } = input;
      return await ctx.prisma.post.findUnique({
        where: { id: postId },
        include: { Category: true, author: true },
      });
    }),
```